# Sticky widget being cut off Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, sidebar, sticky

I am trying to make the sidebar scroll with the page on [this page](https://www.nycofficesuites.com/new/?page_id=164).

I've done this by adding this code to the Wordpress custom code section:

```
.sidebar .widget {
    position: fixed;   
}
```

However, as you can see, the sidebar is being cut off and only displaying a few of around 8 fields. I also want to make sure the sidebar starts below the header and ends before the footer.  I am relatively comfortable using css but if this is a jquery fix I am a total beginner.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe those `position: fixed`s are the cause of your problem. I used firebug to deactivate all of them. Still don't see your scrollbar. But that and any other problems should be another question.

Comment: yeah looks like you'll need javascript/jquery to do what you're doing correctly in order to move the widget as you need it because when you get towards the bottom you have to change the positioning a bit - can't be fixed in the same way.

Comment: Thanks.  Can someone help me with the JQuery code please?  Thanks!